# Create new columns based on vector in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

With `dplyr` it is easy to create a new column using `mutate`:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:3, v2 = c('a','b','c'))
> mutate(df, newcol = NA)
  v1 v2 newcol
1  1  a     NA
2  2  b     NA
3  3  c     NA
```

We can also create multiple new columns with a vector using `mutate_at` (shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971624/use-dplyr-mutate-to-create-new-columns-based-on-a-vector-of-column-names)):

```
> cnames <- c('newcol1', 'newcol2', 'newcol3')
> mutate_at(df, cnames, funs(log(v1)))
  v1 v2   newcol1   newcol2   newcol3
1  1  a 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2  2  b 0.6931472 0.6931472 0.6931472
3  3  c 1.0986123 1.0986123 1.0986123
```

**Is there a simple way to initialize these new columns as NA using `dplyr`?**

For example, `mutate_at(df, cnames, funs(v1 * NA))` gives the desired result, but that seems indirect. What I would like is something along the lines of:

```
mutate_at(df, cnames, funs(. = NA)) # Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
```

where we don't need to know the names of any other columns.

(I know this is simply solved with `df[ , cnames] <- NA`, but I'm looking for a solution using `dplyr` functions)

---

EDIT:

Using later versions of `dplyr` the example becomes:

```
mutate_at(df, all_of(cnames), funs(log(v1)))
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug.  You don't need 'v1' there.  any number would be sufficient i.e. 1 or 0 `mutate_at(df, cnames, funs( NA * 0))` or even add `+`

Comment: When I try your example, I get the following error message: 
"Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `newcol1` doesn't exist."
Apparently the values in the vector cnames is expected to be already existing. How did you get your code to work? I'm working with dplyr version 0.8.3 and R version 3.6.3

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel, updated – now I think you need to use `all_of`.

Comment: @C.Braun it still does not work. RStudio would give a warning if `all_of` was required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 `is.na<-`(cnames)
#  v1 v2 newcol1 newcol2 newcol3
#1  1  a      NA      NA      NA
#2  2  b      NA      NA      NA
#3  3  c      NA      NA      NA
```

I hope one `%>%` is `dplyr` enough. ;)

Comment: That is simple, but I feel like there should be a way to do this using `dplyr` functions (more of a personal preference for not using backticked functions). I had noticed that `df %>% '[<-'(, cnames, NA)` works as well, but both interrupt the flow of the `dplyr` chain in my opinion.

Comment: @C.Braun You might know that the `magrittr` package provides a set of aliases for cases like this, see `?magrittr::add`. You could define your own, to make piping more pleasant, e.g. `set_NA <- \`is.na<-\`; df %>% set_NA(cnames)`.